# I am using MStest (.net core) for my test project, Is there a way to continue the test execution on failure?

Tags: mstest, fluent-assertions

I want my test to proceed next line after the assert fails. I tried "try catch block" but tests are not failing. Do we have anything that can fix this issue in fluent assertion [https://fluentassertions.com/] or anyways to handle this in code?

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish, do you have an example you can show?  A try/catch block will suppress any test failures and keep the test from having the failed condition.  Are you trying to run some cleanup?  For this you should look into using a try/finally block, a test cleanup method, or a test class cleanup method.

Comment: I have multiple assert statements in my test method, not in sequence like , now if an assert fails i want to proceed with the next line.  [TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
int a;
Assert();
int b;
Assert()
}

Comment: I am aware of multiple assertions but am looking for something equivalent to the soft assertion like (https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/01/13/hard-and-soft-assertions-in-selenium/#:~:text=To%20deal%20with%20the%20disadvantage,next%20step%20after%20assert%20statement.) in mstest c#

Answer (score 1):

Sounds you are searching for [AssertionScope](https://fluentassertions.com/introduction#assertion-scopes) of FluentAssertions.

```cs
using (new AssertionScope())
{
    5.Should().Be(10); // will fail but not throw
    DoSomeOtherStuff();
} // assertion will raise exception
```

All failed asserts will be collected until `AssertionScope` is disposed.

Comment: it fails at the first verify, I want to continue to the next{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            int a = 5;
            int b = 6;
            Verify(a, b);
            a = 5;
            b = 5;
            Verify(a, b);
   
        }

        public void Verify(int a, int b)
        {
            using (new AssertionScope())
            {
                a.Should().Be(6); // will fail but not throw
                b.Should().Be(5);

            }

        }

    }
}

Comment: Your requirement is unfortunately still a bit unclear. A unit test shall ultimately fail if (at least) one condition was wrong. With the help of AssertionScope, you can delay the failure as long as necessary. Is that not enough for you?

Comment: How did you solve the problem, @vigneshkec?
Was my answer helping, please vote for it.
If not, can you share your solution or update your question?

Comment: I have written a custom assert function with a try-catch block, and in the catch, I will add an exception to Testcontext properties. at the end of the test [TestCleanup], I added a condition to check for new properties in the test context if found I will print and fail the tests. Assertion scope will not work in my case because my asserts are not in sequence.